# Unknown Filesystem type while mounting SDXC card

Tags: 13.10, mount, sd-card

I'm trying to mount my 64 GB SDXC card into my computer's internal card reader but I get the following message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdd at /media/renato/disk: 
Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdd" "/media/renato/disk"' 
exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

What can I do to make Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit read my SD card so I can download my pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have the exfat drivers to write. You could try the `-ro` option in your mount command, it should work (but you obviously won't be able to write on your card^^).

Here's what I found on Google (in French) : [ubuntu-fr.org](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/exfat)

Exfat (or fat64) is the latest AND non open-source file format by Microsoft, to overcome the 4gb limit size of fat32. To access exfat with read-write, add the ppa `relan/exfat` and install the package `exfat-utils` :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:relan/exfat
sudo apt-get update -qq
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils
```

---

Another solution would be to format your card in NTFS (non open-source, but Ubuntu should be able to write it with `ntfs-3g` package installed) or EXT4 format (free open-source yeay!), but it depends on the use you have of the card.

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemsExplained) you can learn more about the various formats.

To change the format of your card, you can use a GUI programm like [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/features.php) (root access needed) :

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fuse-exfat : Depends: fuse-utils (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Install `exfat-utils` only, apparently fuse-exfat is not maintained on 13.10

Comment: Hmm, but how do I do that?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install exfat-utils`

Comment: you can accept my answer (the V sign on the left of my answer) to close your thread.